# Where to find resources about study skills and strategies of immediate impact?

Tags: aids

Where can research and resources be found, about study skills and strategies for university math of immediate impact? To wit, how do I efficiently find categorical, pragmatic advice about learning/studying math, of instant effect?

I exemplify a few examples which I lighted upon with Google and Amazon.com:

- [Lara Alcock, *How to Study for a Mathematics Degree*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Study-Mathematics-Degree-Lara-Alcock/dp/0199661324)
- [Kevin Houston, *How to Think Like a Mathematician*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Think-Like-Mathematician-Undergraduate/dp/052171978X)
- [Martin Gould and Edward Hurst, *Bridging the Gap to University Mathematics*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bridging-University-Mathematics-Edward-Hurst/dp/1848002890)

I originally posed this as an [Example Question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators/64305#64305).

Comment: I don't know what tags would be appropriate, but I don't think `aids` is a good tag.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but many of the answers on [this other question](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/198/books-autobiographies-references-on-how-mathematicians-perform-their-mathemati) answer this one as well.